# How to process javascript code inside html template (jsdoc / grunt-jsdoc)

Tags: gruntjs, jsdoc, jsdoc3

jsdoc is not parsing `<script>` content (valid JS with valid JSDOC comments).

**How to fix?**

Is it even possible to scan html files and document code inside **script** tag?

```
jsdoc: {
      dist: {
        src: ['assets/js/**/*.js', 'templates/users/*.html', 'README.md'],
        options: {
          destination: '.dev/jsdoc',
          template: 'node_modules/ink-docstrap/template',
          configure: '.jsdoc.conf.json'
        }
      }
    },
```

**.jsdoc.conf.json**

```
{
  "tags": {
    "allowUnknownTags": true
  },
  "plugins": ["plugins/markdown"],
  "templates": {
    "logoFile": "",
    "cleverLinks": false,
    "monospaceLinks": false,
    "dateFormat": "ddd MMM Do YYYY",
    "outputSourceFiles": true,
    "outputSourcePath": true,
    "systemName": "Django",
    "footer": "",
    "copyright": "DocStrap Copyright © 2012-2015 The contributors to the JSDoc3 and DocStrap projects.",
    "navType": "vertical",
    "theme": "readable",
    "linenums": true,
    "collapseSymbols": false,
    "inverseNav": true,
    "protocol": "html://",
    "methodHeadingReturns": false
  },
  "markdown": {
    "parser": "gfm",
    "hardwrap": true
  },
  "opts": {
    "sort": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the issue : https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/721 
this is not supported by jsdoc. However, there's a plugin to achieve parsing HTML file in pull request : https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/pull/723